# SWF Decider started AFTER workflow submitted never sees Decision Events

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-swf

I'm trying to simulate the case where I have a Decider, and it goes down, for either maintenance or it's updating (I will eventually do this for the worker as well unless I just move it to Lambda). Anyway, I am noticing that if I shut down my decider, then I start an execution (using the SWF Console), then start my decider I never receive any Decision* events. It's like it gets lost forever.

My guess is I am missing something obvious. I am using boto3 to `poll_for_decision_task`

http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/swf.html#SWF.Client.poll_for_decision_task

Is there some other initial step I should be taking to get any previous executions that have not been seen by the decider when it comes online?

**BONUS Problem**:

Sometimes, even when I have the decider running, and it's polling for a decision task, and I submit a task from the AWS Console, the decider is never triggered.

**BONUS BONUS Problem**:
If the decider DOES get the execution event, and it does a `StartTimer`, say for 10s, if I quit the decider AFTER the StartTimer is scheduled and then I restart the decider, the TimerFired event never comes though.

In both bonus cases, `get_workflow_execution_history` shows the execution is there. (http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/swf.html#SWF.Client.get_workflow_execution_history)

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is availability, why not run multiple deciders? When a decision task is scheduled, SWF guarantees it can only be used once.

Not seen decisions getting lost before. I would often find that a restarted decider might take some time to pick up a decision (up to 60s) and, if your 'scheduleToStartTimeout' was less than 60s, then it may timeout before the decider got it.

BONUS Problem:
- Could be a number of things, but expect the taskList name doesn't match or a decider delay to pick it up may trigger a timeout.